# ¿Cómo hacer que un botón no vuelva a aparecer después de presionarlo?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, navigation

Tengo una aplicación en la cuál al presionar un botón te lleva a una serie de fragmentos para responder encuestas. EL problema es que quiero presionarlo y ya no se vuelva a mostrar debido a que cuando lo presionas avanzas a otro fragmento y así sucesivamente hasta volver al fragmento principal (fragmento en el que se presiono el botón por primera vez) . No tengo la menor idea de como, intente con `invalidate`, `isEnabled = false` e `isClickeable = false`. Todas esas funciones las intente así:

```
class Home : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.btnIrEncuestaTuto.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.home2_to_z_encuesta_tutorial)
            btnIrEncuestaTuto.isClickable = false //Aquí intente agregar la sugerencia de una respuesa
        }
    }
}
```

El la parte del `onViewCreated` es código para avanzar a la siguiente pantalla. Yo supongo que la función o atributo debería de colocarse ahí enseguida del `binding.btnIrEncuestaTuto.setOnClickListener {`

Este es el código botón en el fragmento:

```
        android:id="@+id/btnIrEncuestaTuto"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:text="Una encuesta disponible!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.439"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.306" />
```

Aquí esta el como van los fragmentos y el que esta solo a la izquierda es el fragmento principal del cual puse el código más arriba. Del fragmento principal hay 2 acciones que van a otros 2 fragmentos. Quiero que cuando presione mi botón en el fragmento principal y me dirija a la siguiente pantalla(que como se puede ver en la imagen, te manda a otro fragmento, y al final vuelve al fragmento principal) ya no este el botón. [image]

Comment: En principio, es como dices: basta con desactivarlo en el listener, pero si ese listener lleva a otra pantalla, ¿qué más da que ese botón se desactive si ya no se va a ver?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que al final de acabar esas pantallas se volverá al main, donde estaba el botón que te lleva esas pantallas, y el fin es una vez que sea presionado, desaparezca para cuando vuelvas al main

Comment: A tu pregunta le faltan detalles importantes para poder ser respondida. Este es un problema de navegación y sin embargo no muestras como llegas o vuelves al fragment. También deberías corregir el título porque deshabilitar un botón al presionarlo y deshabilitarlo al volver al fragment son cosas muy diferentes.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, ya realice los cambios.

Comment: Aún es confusa. El titúlo sigue diciendo que quieres deshabilitarlo después de presionarlo pero la descripción dice que quieres que desaparezca al completar la encuesta, lo cual es contradictorio. Qué quieres que suceda si el usario está en el primer fragment de la encuesta y presiona el back button? Y qué significa exactamente "desaparezca"? Quieres deshabilitarlo o hacerlo invisible? Por favor se  claro.

Comment: Corregido, código del nav_graph y título actualizado.

Comment: Bien pero no aclaraste la duda más importante. Cuando quieres ocultar el botón? Al completar la encuesta o al presionar el botón??

Comment: Hahaha una disculpa. Cuando se presione el botón, que desaparezca.

Comment: Corrigelo en la pregunta, sigue diciendo "cuando se acabe la encuesta(todos los fragmentos de la misma), no vuelva a aparecer". Entonces no es problema de navegación así que deberías eliminar todo el código que agregaste porque ahora es irrelevante.

Comment: Corregido, y disculpa por los errores, solo quiero saber como hacer esto, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ocultar un elemento debes usar `isVisible = false` o `visibility = View.GONE`. Pero no puedes simplemente ponerlo dentro del clickListener porque el fragment se destruye cuando navegas y, al regresar se crea una nueva instancia de ese fragment por lo que se pierde cualquier cambio que le hayas realizado a la primera instancia.

Necesitas guardar el estado en algún lugar que puedas leer desde la próxima instancia y entonces mostrar u ocultar el botón según corresponda

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (leerEstado())
        binding.btnIrEncuestaTuto.isVisible = false
    else
        binding.btnIrEncuestaTuto.setOnClickListener {
            guardarEstado()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.home2_to_z_encuesta_tutorial)
        }
}
```

Por supuesto tu deberías crear tus propios métodos y nombrarlos apropiadamente.  No puedo decirte cómo o dónde guardar el estado porque hay demasiadas opciones y eres el único que puede saber cuál encaja mejor en tu applicación. En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options) puedes ver las opciones más comunes.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente preguntabas:

> ¿Cómo deshabilitar un botón? (Kotlin)

Puede usar alguna de esta propiedades `isEnabled`  o  `isClickable` asignandoles el valor `false`:

```
btnIrEncuestaTuto.isEnabled = false
btnIrEncuestaTuto.isClickable = false
```

pero ahora preguntas como deshabilitarlo y que no aparezca:

> ¿Cómo deshabilitar un botón después de presionarlo y que al volver, no
> vuelva a aparecer? (Kotlin)

Si lo que deseas es que no aparezca simplemente cambia su propiedad `isVisible` a `false` :

```
btnIrEncuestaTuto.isVisible = false
```

Comment: Me encantaría decirte que  `btnIrEncuestaTuto.isEnabled = false ó
btnIrEncuestaTuto.isClickable = false` me funcionan, pero no...